# How can I implement transactions with Laravel's Illuminate Database class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel's [Illuminate Database](https://github.com/illuminate/database) as a standalone in a project.

As the Laravel's docs show there seems to be a [DB::transaction function](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions) which I can access directly. 
But I'm not getting that when I include the Database\Capsule\Manager class according to the short wiki on Illuminate's Github page.

How can I access the function? It seems I have to include another class, but which one? 
I don't know the internals of Laravel!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have to include another class, add the connection like it is telling you, and the rest the package will do for you.

To call the DB::transaction method use the following after following the wiki;

```
Capsule::transaction(function() {
    //Your code...
})
```

or manually like so;

```
try {

    Capsule::beginTransaction();

    //Your code....

    Capsule::commit();

} catch (\Exception $e){

    Capsule::rollback();
    //Handle anything else....

}
```

Comment: Can I use it like this?

`Capsule::beginTransaction();`

Comment: That worked. Thanks! :)

When I browsed to the actual Capsule\Manager class, it didn't have those functions. So I didn't now whether it'd work or not. :)

Comment: It works because the underlying connection class, which is created when you use the addConnection method, have all the methods you are want to yuse, i.e. build your query with.